# Kubernetes Ingress unable to find the service for root page

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using the following defnition for my Ingress yaml. All the other endpoints like https://myhomepage.com/apis/* are working fine but when tyring to access the root page https://myhomepage.com, nginx ingress is returning a 404 :

```
(logmessage : x.x.x.x - - [29/Dec/2021:04:32:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36" 340 0.001 [upstream-default-backend] [] 127.0.0.1:8181 185 0.000 404 4e512ad2cdf198e41713f8dd79dc75ae)
```

And I made sure that the portforward on my local to myhomepage-nginx-service:8090 is working fine.

**Describe ingress output:**

```html
Name:             nginx-ingress
Namespace:        dev
Address:          127.0.0.1
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  zerossl-myhomepage terminates myhomepage.com
Rules:
  Host            Path  Backends
  ----            ----  --------
myhomepage.com
                  /               myhomepage-nginx-service:8090 (10.1.210.91:80)
                  /apis/*     api-service:8090 (10.1.210.102:8090)
Annotations:      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: true
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: true
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:           <none>
```

**Ingress YAMl:**

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public"
    #cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-stg"
    #acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    #____________Enable CORS__________________
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
       more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
    #____________Enable CORS__________________
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - myhomepage.com
      secretName: zerossl-myhomepage
      #secretName: letsencrypt-realstg-cert
  rules:
  - host: myhomepage.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: myhomepage-service
            port: 
              number: 8090
```

**Service YAML:**

```html
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myhomepage-service
  labels:
    app: myhomepage-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: myhomepage-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 8090
      targetPort: 80
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myhomepage-deployment
  name: myhomepage-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myhomepage-deployment
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myhomepage-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myhomepage-deployment
        image: userename/repo-images:myhomepagecom
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockercreds
```

Comment: your service `myhomepage-nginx-service` both are in same namespace ? make sure your service `myhomepage-nginx-service` and ingress in same namespace.

Comment: well, my ingress and all services are not in same namespace but ingress is able to find other services.

Comment: please share the YAML of ingress in the question if possible.

Comment: share `YAML` of your `Ingress` and `Service`

Comment: @HarshManvar YAML's have been posted

Comment: @hesmoh  YAML's have been posted

Comment: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public"` are you using any ingress controller like nginx ingress controller ?

Comment: @HarshManvar Yes, I am using nginx ingress controller

Comment: Did you set the class by default class name should be Nginx instead public.